# Can't call object method on previous state in setState hook inside subscribe body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, setstate

Trying to update an objects state using the useState hook does not work inside a  RxJS subject subscribe body, but does outside it. (annotated with the comments in the second code section)

The error I receive is: TypeError: eventMap.addEvent is not a function

My goal is to call addEvent from EventMap with the event from the backpageMessageSubject$, and later on passing the returned array from getNthEvent method to a child component.

```
class EventMap {
     eventArrays;
     constructor() {
         this.eventArrays = new Map();
     }

    addEvent = (id, data) => {
        this.eventArrays.has(id)
            ? this.eventArrays.get(id).push(data)
            : this.eventArrays.set(id, [data]);
        return this.eventArrays;
    }

    getNthEvent = (n) => {
        const result = [];
        for (let key of this.eventArrays.keys()) {
            result.push(this.eventArrays.get(key)[n]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
export default function MarbleDiagram(props) {
    const [eventMap, setEventMap] = useState(new EventMap());

    // Stream of events for this observable.
    const event$ = backpageMessageSubject$.pipe(
        filter(message => message.type === 'event'),
        map(message => message.event),
        filter(event => event.observable === props.observable)
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const eventSubscription = event$.subscribe(event => {
            setEventMap(eventMap => eventMap.addEvent(1, 1)); // This does trigger error.
        });

        setEventMap(eventMap => eventMap.addEvent(1, 1)); // This does not trigger error.

        return () => {
            eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);
}
```

subject origin:

```
export const backpageMessageSubject$ = new Subject();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've done `setEventMap(eventMap => eventMap.addEvent(1, 1))`, what you have in state for the event map is the **return value** of `eventMap.addEvent`, which isn't an `EventMap` instance. So later when you try to use it, it fails because what you're using (a `Map`) doesn't have `addEvent`.

Since items in state must not be directly modified, you'll need to update `EventMap` so that it returns a new instance of the map with the added event, rather than mutating the existing map, along these lines:

```
class EventMap {
     eventArrays;
     constructor(eventArrays = new Map()) { // Note accepting a parameter
         this.eventArrays = eventArrays;
     }

    addEvent = (id, data) => {
        // Copy the current map, reusing the same arrays
        const eventArrays = new Map(this.eventArrays);
        // Get the current array for this `id`
        const current = eventArrays.get(id);
        if (!current) {
            // We don't have it, create a new one in the new map
            eventArrays.set(id, [data]);
        } else {
            // We have it, copy its contents to a new array and
            // add the new data to the end, storing it in the
            // new map
            eventArrays.set(id, [...current, data]);
        }
        // Create a new EventMap with those arrays and return it
        return new EventMap(eventArrays);
    }

    getNthEvent = (n) => {
        const result = [];
        for (let key of this.eventArrays.keys()) {
            result.push(this.eventArrays.get(key)[n]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```